# Detectar cuando una llamada terminó en android

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, alert

Mi aplicación por medio de un `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mobile));
context.startActivity(intent);
Toast.makeText(context, "Llamando a: "+nombre, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Realizo una llamada, pero necesito saber cuando la llamada ya termino para mostrar una alerta (Específicamente para calificar la llamada), Existe alguna manera, bueno creo que si debe existir ya que

> Truecaller realiza algo simimilar a lo que yo estoy necesitando

Comment: Hola Wilson, no se puede detectar esto mediante un Intent, en este caso debes usar un BroadcastReceiver, @WilsonCajisaca revisa la respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Detectar cuando una llamada recibida termino en Android.

Tienes que realizarlo mediante un `BroadcastReceiver`, define una clase que va a ser llamada mediante el intent-filter :

```
  <receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

La clase extiende de `BroadcastReceiver` e implementa el método `onIncomingCallEnded()`, **el método `onIncomingCallEnded()` cual determina cuando una llamada recibida termino**:

```
protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
 
}
```

**Si deseas detectar cuando una llamada que tu realizas termino, usa el método `onOutgoingCallEnded()`**:

```
protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String savedNumber, Date callStartTime, Date end) {

}
```

---

Esta sería la clase completa:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Date;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String TAG = "myCallReceiver";
    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;

    public CallReceiver() { }

    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("onIncomingCallStarted()",number);
    }

    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onOutgoingCallStarted() number: " + number);
    }

    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onIncomingCallEnded() : (savedNumber: "+ number + ", callStartTime: " +start.toString());
    }

    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String savedNumber, Date callStartTime, Date end) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onOutgoingCallEnded() : (savedNumber: "+ savedNumber + ", callStartTime: " +callStartTime.toString());
    }

    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String incomingNumber, Date start) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onMissedCall() : (savedNumber: "+ incomingNumber + ", callStartTime: " +start.toString());
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive() : (savedNumber: "+ number + ", stateStr: EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)");
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive() : (savedNumber: "+ number + ", stateStr: CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)");
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive() : (savedNumber: "+ number + ", stateStr: CALL_STATE_RINGING)");
            }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Para que sea llamado el `BroadCastReceiver` debes configurarlo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` definiendo los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Ejemplo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
     ...
     ...
     ...

    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```